# Passwordless mysqldump via shell script in /etc/cron.daily

Tags: mysqldump, scripting, my.cnf, password, cron

I'm aware that there are dozens of questions similar to this, but it seems none has a definitive answer to my problem, so that's why I'm posting this... I hope in the right place.

**The problem**:

I have a script placed in `/etc/cron.daily` that performs a daily database backup among the other things. It works fine as long as there is a password hardcoded into the script for the [mysqldump](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump.html) command.

```
#!/bin/sh
$ mysqldump -u [uname] -p[pass] db_name > db_backup.sql
```

However, not wanting to have the password in the script, I've set up `~/.my.cnf` file (chmod 600) with my user's password stored there so the `mysqldump` command in the script would be passwordless.

```
~/.my.cnf    
[mysqldump]
password="pass"
```

---

```
#!/bin/sh    
$ mysqldump -u [uname] db_name > db_backup.sql
```

When I run this new script manually from the command line as root it works like a charm.

```
sudo sh /etc/cron.daily/daily-backup-script
```

But when `cron` wants to run it it's unable to dump the database giving the following error:

```
mysqldump: Got error: 1045: Access denied for user 'user'@'localhost' (using password: NO) when trying to connect.
```

So, I assume `cron` doesn't have appropriate privilege to perform the passwordless `mysqldymp` command in the script, with password placed in `~/.my.cnf`, however the script and the passwordless `mysqldump` command IN IT are working flawlessly from the command line with `sudo`.

**Effort so far:**

1. I've tried `sudo` in front of the `mysqldump` command in the script.
2. I've tried `sudo -u user` in front of the `mysqldump` command in the script.
3. I've chown-ed the `~/.my.cnf` file as `root:root`.

Comment: Looks like you may want to [merge your accounts](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Solved with the help of [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/395228).

`cron` doesn't know the path to `~/.my.cnf`, so as per the [MYSQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_defaults-extra-file) you need to specify the path to the `.my.cnf` file.

The proper passwordless `mysqldump` command in the shell script triggered via `cron` should be:

```
mysqldump --defaults-extra-file=/path/to/.my.cnf -u [uname] db_name > db_backup.sql
```

Works like a charm.

Comment: What's quite intriguing is that I just ran into this problem not with cron but with bacula (post backup commands and here a script); my /etc/cron.daily script that backs up all databases had no problem finding the .my.cnf file. This threw me off and so after the bacula failure I made sure. Yes. It's a new install that made me notice it; whereas in the more recent versions of bacula on my Fedora box it would report a failed backup the older version in CentOS did not so I never noticed it ... and since I did full mysql backups nightly it wasn't a real issue I suppose but still. Ta for the fix!